# Entity Framework does not update when using a many to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using a Many to Many relation from `Class1` to `Class2`. exactaly like this:

```
public class Class1{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Class2> Classes2 { get; set; }

    //...
}

public class Class2{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //... no navigational parameter
    // there is no need for navigational when using fluent API below.
    // However the navigational presence does not affects the issue
}
```

and fluent API

```
OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

    modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>().HasMany(a => a.Classes2).WithMany();

}
```

EF creates all table schema with the `Class1Class2` intermediate table.

Then I my application prints the `Class1` to the view and got the modified `Class1` from binding it back from user where the user is able to remove, or add `Classes2`. (I already checked, all data is correctly bound in the `entity` instance).

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind()] Class1 entity) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return View();
}
```

However `SaveChanges` does not updates many to many data.

What can I do to correctly update the new bound many to many parameters?

**I just want to remove or add relation, I don't want do add or remove Classes2 records.**

Comment: afaik, many-to-many relationship requires both class to hold the navgational property - while one-to-many only needed on the class that  become the 'one' in the relation. anyway `virtual IList<Class2> Classes2 { get; set; }` tried to change it `public virtual..`?

Comment: There is no need of navigational parameters when using Fluent API. however navigational properties does not affects this issue. i forgot to write 'public' in the question. already edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've replaced the original answer I gave here because of a misunderstanding as to what was being asked.

As it was later cleared up, I realised that the old answer had no bearing on the question.

So, here is my take on many to many mapping with EF, and updating the relationships involved.

I've used 'EF' in the names of the entities (`TeacherEFs`, `StudentEFs`, and `TeacherEFsStudentEFs`) where they will be used by Entity Framework's many to many mapping.

The others (`Teachers`, `Students`, `TeachersStudents`) are used for normal CRUD operations where you control all table data.

Although you can use fluent API, data annotations are sufficient to set this up, example entities are shown below for both methods:

```
// Manual method - you control the relationship table
public class Teacher
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<TeachersStudents> TeachersStudents { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<TeachersStudents> TeachersStudents { get; set; }
}

public class TeachersStudents
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_Teacher_Student", 1)]
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_Teacher_Student", 2)]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TeacherId")]
    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StudentId")]
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}

// Automatic method - Entity Framework controls the relationship table
public class TeacherEF
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<StudentEF> StudentEFs { get; set; }
}

public class StudentEF
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<TeacherEF> TeacherEFs { get; set; }
}
```

This will generally be the result of generating the migration for the above entities:

```
public override void Up()
{
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.TeacherEFs",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
        
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.StudentEFs",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
        
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Teachers",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
        
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Students",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
        
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.TeacherEFStudentEFs",
            c => new
                {
                    TeacherEF_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    StudentEF_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.TeacherEF_Id, t.StudentEF_Id })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.TeacherEFs", t => t.TeacherEF_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.StudentEFs", t => t.StudentEF_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.TeacherEF_Id)
            .Index(t => t.StudentEF_Id);
        
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.TeachersStudents",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    TeacherId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    StudentId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Teachers", t => t.TeacherId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Students", t => t.StudentId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => new { t.TeacherId, t.StudentId }, name: "IX_Teacher_Student");
}
```

Notice that Entity Framework added a third table to the database using the relationships we supplied in the classes:

```
public virtual ICollection<TeacherEF> TeachersEF { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<StudentEF> StudentsEF { get; set; }
```

It used the `Id` properties from both entities and combined them to create a composite and unique primary key.

As can now be seen, if you add relationships between `TeacherEFs` and `StudentEFs` those relationships will be placed in this table - there will not be any information regarding the relationship in the parent tables (`TeacherEFs` and `StudentEFs`).

There is also a Cascade Delete set so that if a `TeacherEF` is removed from the `TeacherEFs` table, all relationships to that `TeacherEF` in the `TeacherEFsStudentEFs` table will be removed (to prevent orphaned data).
Therefore, to add or remove relationships between `TeacherEFs` and `StudentEFs`, this third table is the only one to be updated.

This relationship data can be updated automatically by Entity Framework, or controlled manually by yourself.

Personally, I prefer to control this (because I like know exactly what is happening with the data directly); as you can see from above, to control this, you would want to be working with the `TeachersStudents` table yourself, adding and removing the Ids of the `Teachers` and `StudentEFs` at will (utilising any existing Id).

The alternative is to let Entity Framework do the work for you behind the scenes, but in this case you will need to let Entity Framework know every change to make in the `TeacherEFsStudentEFs` table via the relationships of the `TeacherEF` and `StudentEF` entities.

Because you will not have access to the relationship table directly, you will need to load all `TeacherEFs` and `StudentEFs` that will have their relationships changed i.e. added or removed. Then set the state of each of those entities to whether the related item is to be added or removed. Entity Framework will then work out which of the rows in the relationship table (`TeacherEFsStudentEFs`) need to be altered, and then finally perform the actions.

Personally, I find this a bit convoluted and you have to hit the database before performing any required update. This is the reason that I prefer to control the data in the relationship table and only hit the database on `SaveChanges();`

***We'll look at two scenarios:***

- You have existing Teachers and Students in the database.
- You wish to add a new relationship.
- You select a Teacher, then relate a Student.

  What you want to do is place both of those Ids into the relationship table.

**Method 1** (my preference).

**Manual CRUD as normally carried out:**

- You have existing Teachers and Students in the database.
- You wish to add a new relationship.
- You select a Teacher, then relate a Student.
- What you want to do is place both of those Ids into the relationship table.

This can be done using the `TeachersStudents` entity, populating both of those properties with the `Id`s of both the selected `Teacher` and the `Student` that are to be related, then calling `SaveChanges()` (normal CRUD having an entity for the relationship table).

However, what if that same relationship was just added by someone else? It would fail on the unique constraint! You could handle this error gracefully, or if it would be meaningful, you could notify the user that the particular relationship they tried to add already exists.

- You have existing Teachers and Students in the database.
- You wish to edit an existing relationship.
- You select a Teacher, then change a Student to a different one.
- What you want to do is change the StudentId in the relationship table via its Id.

You would select a `TeachersStudents` record (with its `Id`, `TeacherId`, and `StudentId`), loading the `Teacher` and `Student` data for display (using a view model preferably), as well as a list of alternatives to choose from for the edit.

Now you can let the user change either the `Student` and update the existing record related by its `Id` and the new `StudentId` from an `Edit` method.

- You have existing Teachers and Students in the database.
- You wish to remove a relationship.
- You display the available relationships to remove.
- You select a relationship.
- What you want to do is remove the record with the given Id from the relationship table.

This method allows you to send your single entity (or multiple if you are allowing many removals at once on the UI) to the server, to a Delete method to remove the relationships,

The advantage of the above is that all data in the database tables are handled the same way using basic CRUD.

I won't give a code sample for the CRUD operations of the relationship table for Method 1, as we all know how to do that.

**Method 2.**

**Using Entity Framework to do the work:**

Apart from initially loading all of the data that will appear on the UI (as mentioned for Method 1), when you send the changes back to the server, you will need to:

Loop through the passed in `TeacherEFs` you have received and retrieve their data from storage along with their related `StudentEFs`.

Loop through the passed in `TeacherEFs` and compare each one with those retrieved from storage to see if a `StudentEF` has been added or removed.

Set each stored `TeacherEF`'s `StudentEF` Collection to add and/or remove as appropriate.

Finally, you can call `SaveChanges()`.

Entity Framework will perform the required edits to the `TeacherEFsStudentEFs` table for you after the entities' relationships have been set.

This is similar to if you were to create CRUD pages for an entity (for TeacherCourse details for example) but never loading the Id and existing properties for it.

Now the user can add all sorts of data to the properties (and specify the Id if they know it), but on sending back to the server, you don't know what you have - you will have to interrogate the storage to see if the Course exists, then check if it is an add, edit, or delete and then perform the required action.

Here is an example of how to do it the Entity Framework 'black box' way.
The example uses a single `TeacherEF` and updates its `StudentEF` collection.
If you wish to send multiple `TeacherEF`s to the server for updating, just alter the code to loop through that collection.

```
public ActionResult Edit(TeacherEF teacherEF)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var context = new MyContext())
                {
                    TeacherEF existingTeacherEF = context.TeacherEFs.Include("StudentEFs").FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == teacherEF.Id);

                    if (teacherEF.StudentEFs == null)
                    {
                        teacherEF.StudentEFs = new List<StudentEF>();
                    }

                    // Add new StudentEfs to the existingTeacherEF
                    List<StudentEF> studentEfsToAdd = new List<StudentEF>();

                    foreach (StudentEF studentEf in teacherEF.StudentEFs)
                    {
                        // Use a loop/where clause/extension method  etc. on the passed in teacherEF's StudentEFs to see if they are already related in the existingTeacherEF.
                        // If not, add them to the list of studentEFsToAdd.
                        if (existingTeacherEF != null)
                        {
                            bool match = false;
                            foreach (StudentEF studentLookup in existingTeacherEF.StudentEFs)
                            {
                                if (studentLookup.Id == studentEf.Id)
                                {
                                    match = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (!match)
                            {
                                // If we do not have a match (the existingTeacher's StudentEFs do not contain the one we are currently looking at ('student')...)
                                // Let's add this 'student' to studentEfsToAdd.
                                studentEfsToAdd.Add(studentEf);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // No need for action - already related
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Delete non-existant StudentEfs from the existingTeacherEF
                    List<StudentEF> studentEfsToDelete = new List<StudentEF>();

                    if (existingTeacherEF != null)
                    {
                        foreach (StudentEF studentEf in existingTeacherEF.StudentEFs)
                        {
                            bool match = false;
                            // Use a loop/where clause/extension method  etc. on the passed in teacherEF's StudentEFs to see if they are already related in the existingTeacherEF.
                            // If not, add them to the list of studentEFsToAdd.
                            foreach (StudentEF studentLookup in teacherEF.StudentEFs)
                            {
                                if (studentLookup.Id == studentEf.Id)
                                {
                                    match = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            if (!match)
                            {
                                // If we do not have a match (the teacherEF's StudentEFs contains a 'student' that is not already related with existingTeacherEF...)
                                // Let's add this 'student' to studentEfsToDelete.

                                studentEfsToDelete.Add(studentEf);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // No need for action - already related
                            }
                        }

                        // Update the context with the StudentEFs we have, and Add or Delete them from the existingTeacherEF before SaveChanges();
                        foreach (StudentEF studentEf in studentEfsToAdd)
                        {
                            if (context.Entry(studentEf).State == EntityState.Detached)
                            {
                                context.StudentEFs.Attach(studentEf);
                            }

                            existingTeacherEF.StudentEFs.Add(studentEf);
                        }

                        foreach (StudentEF studentEf in studentEfsToDelete)
                        {
                            if (context.Entry(studentEf).State == EntityState.Detached)
                            {
                                context.StudentEFs.Attach(studentEf);
                            }

                            existingTeacherEF.StudentEFs.Remove(studentEf);
                        }
                    }

                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            return View(teacherEF);
        }
```

Comment: If I set one child2 instance to state to deleted. Will it delete the Child2 from the database or just remove the relation? I would like to remove just the relation. I guess that setting a state to delete will delete it from the database

Comment: If you removed the relationship from the object, it would not be updated in the database - only if EF is told that an object exists in the storage and needs updating will it affect it. On saying that though, removing the item from the collection of the parent, but not removing it from the database, would mean that the next time you load the parent from the database, the child that was 'removed' previously will be loaded again...

Comment: I have faced same problem  before and I solved the problem in this same way. However, I think this is an awful approach to apply in development. I am eagerly waiting for a new, better and feasible solution.

Comment: @StevePadmore. i'm saying that,  if i do set `db.Entry(child).State = EntityState.Deleted` it WILL BE deleted from database. Not just the relation.

Comment: Yes, it will delete from database upon SaveChanges ().

Comment: I need to remove or add relation, I don't want do add or remove Classes2 records.

Comment: Another OK, I think I know what you want now. Just to confirm: you have two tables (probably with existing data in both) and you want to add and remove relationships between the two - but not delete the actual records in the tables?

Comment: @Daniel Santos, hi there. I've deleted the old answer I gave and replaced it with one I think is what you're after, hope it does the trick!